# How to maintain hygiene of toothbrush

Tags: toothbrush

Shall i be interested in hygiene of toothbrush, and if so:

How to keep toothbrush clean for long period (1-2 months)
if you use toothbrush to clean your teeth without any toothpaste

I'm looking for solution, for cleaning the toothbrush, in these priorities:

1. Contains no herbal
2. Contains herbal
3. Anything else

My ideas:

1. Put Activated Charcoal in cup, and store there head of toothbrush

2.Put green tea, cinnamon powder, ginger powder and coconut oil in cup, and store there head of toothbrush.
 Change mixture in the cup, in 2-3 days. Will this work?

This question is follow up to many articles, explaining how badly is to drink directly from water bottle/container for week or so without cleaning it.

Comment: Why not just exchange it every few months, as recommended? Furthermore, *do* use toothpaste. Toothbrushes are not designed to work without it: they are *much less effective*! (They will still remove plaque just fine but that’s not the only reason for brushing.)

Comment: Millions of people have been doing nothing more than rinsing and allowing toothbrushes to air dry for over a hundred years. To my knowledge, no one has ever suffered harm from this. The few bacteria that survive on an air-dried toothbrush aren't likely to be relevant to a mouth that is teeming with billions of bacteria.

Comment: https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/294945.php sounds like need to autoclave daily